# JSoup is not fully rendering a long page

Tags: java, android, jsoup

There is a [website](https://student.utm.utoronto.ca/timetable/timetable?yos=1&session=20199) that I am trying to scrape information from using the JSoup library. The problem is that only a portion of the page is in the response.

Here is my code:

```java
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(
        String.format("https://student.utm.utoronto.ca/timetable/timetable?yos=%s&session=20199", i))
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36")
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .timeout(600000)
        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
        .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9")
        .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8")
        .header("Cache-Control","max-age=0")
        .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
        .header("Host", "student.utm.utoronto.ca")
        .header("Sec-Fetch-Mode","navigate")
        .execute();
```

I tried to replicate as many headers as I could from the request headers in my browser.

I'm suspecting that javascript was run after initially loading the page, and that is why I am not getting the full page in the response.

This is the last element with a `tr` tag:

```
      <tr id="tr_MAT102H5FTUT0125" class=" TUT W1 meeting_section OL0 todAft"> 
       <td> </td> 
       <td> <label for="MAT102H5FTUT0125">TUT0125</label> </td> 
       <td class="instrTD"> </td> 
       <td class="hideEnrolTD"> 29 </td> 
       <td class="hideEnrolTD"> 35 </td> 
       <td class="hideEnrolTD"> 0 </td> 
       <td class="enrolTD"> 29/35, wait:0 </td> 
       <td> <abbr title="Wednesday">WE</abbr><br> </td> 
       <td class="start_time"> 13:00<br> </td> 
       <td> 14:00<br> </td> 
       <td> MN 2100<br> </td> 
       <td class="noteTD"> </td> 
       <td class="text-right"> 
        <!-- <input type='checkbox' name='courses' id='$checkbox_id' value='MAT102H5F-TUT0125-313:0014:00' aria-label='MAT102H5F TUT0125' /> --> <button name="courses" id="MAT102H5FTUT0125" value="MAT102H5F-TUT0125-313:0014:00" onclick="addCourse($(this))" aria-label="MAT102H5F TUT0125" class="addButton btn btn-sm btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span class="button-text"> Add to Plan</span></button> </td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr id="tr_MAT102H5FTUT0126" class=" TUT W1 meeting_section OL0 todAft"> 
       <td> </td> 
       <td> <label for="MAT102H5FTUT0126">TUT0126</label> </td> &lt;
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I am expecting the last `tr` tag to represent the last table loaded in the page, which is the course `WGS102H5S` and not `MAT102H5F`.

Not sure if this is useful information, but I am currently programming this in android studio.

Is there any fix for this in JSoup? If not, is there a better library I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Change `.execute();` to `.maxBodySize(0).execute().bufferUp();`
https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#maxBodySize-int-
https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Response.html#bufferUp--